# Why won't my view compile?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sql-view

I want to create a view like this:

```
create or replace view sales_num as 
Select M.Medicine_name , M.Price , count(S.Sales_number)
from Medicine M Join Sales S
on (M.Code=S.Code)
gorup by M.Code ;
```

Error report -

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

What is wrong ?  Even when I correct the typo `gorup` to `group` but it still  doesn't work.

### Edit

Even after correcting the `gorup` typo errors persist.

Comment: Gorup? Presume you mean "group by". Also why are you grouping by a value you are not returning?

Comment: it must be group by. yes. but it doesnt work again

Comment: I've edited the question to indicate that changing `gorup` (one of my personal favorite typo's :-) to `group` errors persist. @Nina - please edit your question and include any errors which are now appearing. (I'm assuming here that fixing the typo must have resulted in different errors). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

- There is an obvious spelling mistake in the word `group`
- When using `group by`, each element in the `select` list must be either an element grouped by, or an aggregated value, but nothing else. So the selections of *Medicine_name* and *price* are both conflicting with this requirement.

Here is one way to fix it, depending on your expectation:

```
Select M.Code,
       Min(M.Medicine_name) as Medicine_name, 
       Min(M.Price) as Price,
       Count(S.Sales_number)
from   Medicine M
Join   Sales S
    on M.Code = S.Code
group by M.Code;
```

If `M.Code` is a unique identifier, then the two added `Min()` aggregated values will just return the expected *Medicine_name* and *Price*. But this is the way Standard SQL wants it, and Oracle follows this rule, as stated in the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html):

> *SelectItems* in the *SelectExpression* with a `GROUP BY` clause must contain only aggregates or grouping columns.

Another way to resolve this, is to amend the `group by` list instead:

```
Select M.Medicine_name, 
       M.Price,
       Count(S.Sales_number)
from   Medicine M
Join   Sales S
    on M.Code = S.Code
group by M.Medicine_name,
         M.Price;
```

You can have several in-between solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with the view:

1. the `group by` clauses must include all the non-aggregate columns
2. columns in views must have legal Oracle names, which means you need to provide an alias for any column which uses a function.

This version of your view will compile:

```
create or replace view sales_num as 
    select m.medicine_name , 
           m.price , 
           count(s.sales_number) tot_sales_number
     from medicine m 
          join sales s on (m.code=s.code)
     group by m.medicine_name,
            m.price;
```